Which pager opens when we view man in terminal?
As we know, there are multiple pagers available like less, more, etc. So, I was wondering which pager opens when we view the manual of any command using:
man command

I do believe that it’s less, but I still want to confirm. Thanks!

Welcome Akash.  Press 'h' for help when man is open... you will see!

Because this answer can change as Ubuntu develops, I'll provide a way to find out that will work now, and will also hopefully work in the future:

At the terminal enter, man man
At the bottom of the terminal, it should indicate how to view man's help.  It's typically the h key.
Press that key.
At the top of the page, it will tell you which pager is being employed.  Right now, I see it's less.


Yes, that answers my question. Thank you!

You're welcome.  Was it less for you too?

It looks like you are new here, and if so, I'll quickly mention that it is customary to click the up-arrow next to "upvote" any answers you consider to be quality and helpful (for all questions, not just this one!), and to also click the checkmark next to an answer if you want to accept it (only for questions you have asked). You can always "unaccept" an answer and accept a different answer later on if you change your mind. Good luck, and welcome!

Yes, 'less' is also my default. Thank you for your insightful advice, I will certainly follow it.

You're welcome.  Happy to help.
